# Bounded real function of convergent real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f_n(x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(x) $ pointwise $\forall x \in X$, with $f_n, f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Under which condition on $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the sequence $ ((g \circ f_n) (x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $, with $(g \circ f_n) (x) : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a convergent subsequence?

My try was: if I take $\hat{x} \in X$ arbitrary but fixed, then is $ ((g \circ f_n) (\hat{x}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ a bounded real sequence, and according to Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem should exist a convergent real subsequence, but already for this first step I found a counterexample, which tells me, that boundedness is not enough:

take $f_n := a - \frac{1}{n}$ (constant for each $x \in X$) with $f_n \nearrow a =:f \hspace{1.5mm} \forall x \in X$, and the bounded function $g(x): \mathbb{1}_{\left\{(-\infty,a)\right\}} (x) - \mathbb{1}_{\left\{[a,\infty)\right\}} (x) $.
Then I do not find any convergent subsequence, as each subsequence of $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ "comes from left", and $g$ is not left-continuous.

Am I wrong somewhere, or boundedness is really not enough?

Comment: Any bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence, regardless of whether you personally can find one. Here $g(f_n)$ is convergent! (It doesn't converge to $g(f)$. whether $g(f_n)$ has a subsequence convergent to $g(f)$ is a totally different question.

Comment: @David thank you for your comment. You are absolutely right! Regarding your second statement, whether $g(f_n)$ has a subsequence convergent to $g(f)$, would it be enough to show, that a subsequence $g(f_{n_m})$ exists, such that for each $x \in X$, $g(f_{n_m}(x))$ converges to $g(f(x))$?